# Crossfilter filter duplicated records

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

Is there any way to filter duplicated values of a dimension using crossfilter?

For example I want to filter the duplicated records by the id dimension

```
id value
1   5
2   7
2   7
```

And I want to obtain

```
id value
1   5
2   7
```

It is important tonote that I dont want to group them by id I just want to filter out the duplicated records. Is this possible?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you'd need to build a custom reducer and keep track of all the key values you've already seen in the group. It's important to keep a count of each of them. Reductio does this under the function called [exception aggregation](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio#aggregations-standard-aggregations-exception-aggregation), but that name will likely change. If you want to do this yourself in your own custom reducer, the relevant implementation is in the [value-count aggregation](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio/blob/master/src/value-count.js) (which tracks the previously seen values) and the [exception count](https://github.com/esjewett/reductio/blob/master/src/exception-count.js) (which does a count aggregation for unique records).